# regular expression to remove square brackets and leave numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have text that start with lines like:

```
[1] some text
[2] another text
[56] third
```

I need to remove the square brackets (only at the beginning of the lines) and leave the number and text as is, like:

```
1 some text
2 another text
56 third
```

I use notepad++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for

```
^\[(\d+)\]
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

- `^` is an anchor for the start of the row
- You have to escape the square brackets, since they have a special meaning in regex
- `\d+` is at least one digit
- Because of the brackets around `\d+`, the number is stored in `\1` so you need `\1` as replace text.

Comment: thumbs up for the explanation